# Writing unwind-like cleanup code in Java

Tags: java, exception, goto

Suppose my classes have a method start() which acquires resources and stop() which releases resources. The start methods of a class may call start() methods of member objects. In case a start() of one of the member objects throws an exception, I have to make sure that stop() is called for all member objects for which start() has succeeded.

```
class X {
    public X ()
    {
        a = new A();
        b = new B();
        c = new C();
        d = new D();
    }

    public void start () throws Exception
    {
        try {
            a.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }

        try {
            b.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            a.stop();
            throw e;
        }

        try {
            c.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            b.stop();
            a.stop();
            throw e;
        }

        try {
            d.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            c.stop();
            b.stop();
            a.stop();
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public void stop ()
    {
        d.stop();
        c.stop();
        b.stop();
        a.stop();
    }

    private A a;
    private B b;
    private C c;
    private D d;
}
```

Note the quadratic growth of cleanup code. What is the best way (least amount of code) to do the cleanup? In C I can do this easily with cleanup code at the bottom of the function and "goto" to jump to the appropriate place, but then Java doesn't have goto. Note that it is not permitted to call stop() on an object that hasn't been start()ed - I'm looking for a code that is exactly equivalent to the above but shorter.

So far the only solution I've come to is to use booleans to remember what was started, like this:

```
public void start () throws Exception
{
    boolean aStarted = false;
    boolean bStarted = false;
    boolean cStarted = false;
    boolean dStarted = false;

    try {
        a.start();
        aStarted = true;
        b.start();
        bStarted = true;
        c.start();
        cStarted = true;
        d.start();
        dStarted = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (dStarted) d.stop();
        if (cStarted) c.stop();
        if (bStarted) b.stop();
        if (aStarted) a.stop();
        throw e;
    }
}
```

I know about "finally" and "try-with-resources", but neither of these seem applicable here because the resources should not be released if there is no exception.

P.S. this is not a question about my use of exceptions, or my program design. This is specifically about cleaning up in case of failures in initialization code.

Comment: What happens when you call `stop` on a non-started resource?

Comment: I've mentioned "that it is not permitted to call stop() on an object that hasn't been start()ed". There may be an assert() in the start() and stop() functions for that.

Comment: Make the stop() method more robust and just call it all the time.

Comment: That would mean having to add a "boolean started" and "if (!started) { return; }" to every class. Which doesn't fit the "least amount of code" requirement.

Comment: what about a try/catch there?

Comment: @bmorris591 try/catch where?

Comment: Can you instead of throwing exceptions in start() return true or false?

Comment: what about keeping an array containing info of which member objects have `started`. In case you hit an error, you simply walk through the array and `stop` them all.

Comment: in first case class X, why dont just make a List<Object> ? then stop() takes the index of started as argument and call stops in the list till that index.

Comment: Agree with bmorris591 - make your stop() method robust enough to be callable even if start() has not been called. I think you are misunderstanding the "least amount of code" requirement. You should avoid duplicating code and unnecessary code but this would be neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I appreciate the all the ideas given, I don't find any of them suitable for widespread use my code. In particular, the stack/list based approach is problematic because of two reasons:

1. The start() wrapper doesn't allow passing arguments to the start methods of the object it calls on.
2. Everything would have to implement an interface like Stoppable. This is problematic because the technique needs to work for externally provided classes and functions, there may not be a start() method but something different.

The idea to just make stop() callable even if the object is not started is not suitable for the same reason - the interface may be out of programmer's control.

In the end I've settled for this, I find that it requires the least amount of boilerplate. An additional benefit is that the resulting stop() method can actually be called even if the object is not started (but this doesn't make the approach pointless because the start and stop functions of the members may be out of programmer's control).

```
class X {
    public X ()
    {
        a = new A();
        b = new B();
        c = new C();
        d = new D();
    }

    public void start () throws Exception
    {
        assert(state == 0);
        try {
            a.start();
            state = 1;
            b.start();
            state = 2;
            c.start();
            state = 3;
            d.start();
            state = 4;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            stop();
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public void stop ()
    {
        if (state >= 4) d.stop();
        if (state >= 3) c.stop();
        if (state >= 2) b.stop();
        if (state >= 1) a.stop();
        state = 0;
    }

    private int state;
    private A a;
    private B b;
    private C c;
    private D d;
}
```

Comment: Now the question is: **Is it safe to read the value of the variable: state in the catch block?**
In C, exception handling is implemented by setjmp/longjmp and it requires local variables to be volatile, if they are modified inside the try block.

Answer (score 4):

How about adding the things you started to a stack, then when you need to stop stuff, pop everything off the stack and stop it.

```
private Deque<Stoppable> toStop = new ArrayDeque<Stoppable>();

public void start() throws Exception {
  try {
    start(a);
    start(b);
    start(c);
    start(d);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    stop();
    throw e;
  }
}

private void start(Stoppable s) throws Exception {
  s.start();
  toStop.push(s);
}

public void stop() {
  while (toStop.size > 0) {
    toStop().pop().stop();
  }
}
```

This requires the stuff you start to have some sort of common `stop()` either through an interface or by subclassing, but I imagine its likely they already do.

Comment: this doesn't actually work as it is written, because the a.start() methods take arguments that would have to be passed through the start() wrapper. Also, the cleanup needs to happen in reverse order.

Comment: if it needs to happen in reverse order, just `reverse` the array and apply same procedure

Comment: @AmbrozBizjak - I changed the list to a stack, also note that the start method is overloaded.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class X
{
    private final List <Stoppable> stoppables = 
        new ArrayList <Stoppable> ();

    private void start (StartStoppable x)
    {
        x.start ();
        stoppables.add (x);
    }

    public void startAll ()
    {
        try
        {
            start (a);
            start (b);
            start (c);
            start (d);
        }
        catch (Throwable ex)
        {
            stopAll ();
            ex.printStackTrace ();
        }
    }

    public void stopAll ()
    {
        for (Stoppable s: stoppables)
        {
            try
            {
                s.stop ();
            }
            catch (Throwable ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace ();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are ok with a linear explosion of code, you can use a `start` method structured like this:

```
public void start () throws Exception
{
    a.start();
    try {
        b.start();
        try {
            c.start();
            try {
                d.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                c.stop();
                throw e;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            b.stop();
            throw e;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        a.stop();
        throw e;
    }
}
```

If you have more than really a few items to start/stop, use a `List` like others suggested.

Comment: Yes I was trying to avoid the nesting, you have to admit this looks ugly :)